# Blender 3.5 using CPU and not GPU even when I have set all settings for rendering

Tags: rendering, gpu

I want to use my GPU (Asus GeForce RTX 4070) when rendering in Blender 3,5. I have updated the latest drive for the GPU. And I have 16GB RAM.
I have seen multiple people having similar problem with Blender not using GPU but still not found a solution to my case:
Edit > Preferences > System > CUDA> Choose GPU (Nivida GeForce RTX 4070) > close the window.

and it is still not working.

Is there anybody that has a solution to this or can see what I missed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe try OptiX (it's generally faster than CUDA) and does it use the GPU when setting viewport shading to rendered?

Comment: What happens if you enable the CPU as well?

Comment: Hello @David, CPU will still see usage when GPU is the selected render device.  Some tasks are better suited to a general purpose processor rather than the highly parallelized but very specific calculations the GPU is designed for.  Task manager also reports usage for basically video gaming by default, you'll have to switch to CUDA on the graph.

Comment: I tried to use OptiX only, CUDA with both selceted and OptiX with both selected and it did not work. 

Allen Simpson. Which graph are you talking about? 
The thing is that today I upgraded my compture from a MSI GeForce GTX 980 to this 4070 GPU. And the rendering time is still the same and therefor it must be that Blender only uses CPU.

Comment: OptiX should get the best results.  Tried a fresh driver update already?

Comment: Yes, the store updated everthing when I bought the new GPU. Can it be so that the GPU is not compatible with Blender?

Comment: No it should work.  If it auto updated you might just go to nvidia.com and get a fresh installer or even try the studio driver available there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my drivers and it worked. The store that had changed the GPU must have done something wrong.